# how to display UITabBarController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I have a UITableViewController in the detailViewController of the tableview I have a infoButton on the navigationBar onClick of that infoButton infoViewController displays . How do I get the navigation bar on infoViewController?

Comment: Embed navigation controller with first controller.And add segue connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to-:  Embed navigation controller with first controller.And add segue connections

Answer (score 0):

You have to use push so it will automatically be pushed to this current navigation stack. but if you try to present it then you will not get any navigation bar.